# Why is my file being overwritten when it is not supposed to?

Tags: c++, time, fstream, stringstream

I am making a routine manager app in C++. I have created a start function which check if a file is already created for that date and if it isn't, it lets you plan your routine. If a routine is already created I want my program to read it out...but my `.txt` file is being overwritten and so nothing is being printed out and I want to know why

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
class task
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int stime, etime;
};
//Time - Sun May 02 09:17:33 2021
int calcMon(std::string month)
{
    int fmonth;
    switch (month[0])
    {
    case 'F':
        fmonth = 02;
        break;
    case 'S':
        fmonth = 9;
        break;
    case 'O':
        fmonth = 10;
        break;
    case 'N':
        fmonth = 11;
        break;
    case 'D':
        fmonth = 12;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (month[0] == 'A' && month[1] == 'p')
    {
        fmonth = 04;
    }
    if (month[0] == 'A' && month[1] == 'u')
    {
        fmonth = 07;
    }
    if (month[0] == 'J')
    {
        if (month[1] == 'a')
        {
            fmonth = 01;
        }
        if (month[1] == 'u' && month[2] == 'n')
        {
            fmonth = 06;
        }
        if (month[1] == 'u' && month[2] == 'l')
        {
            fmonth = 07;
        }
    }
    if (month[0] == 'M' && month[1] == 'a' && month[2] == 'r')
    {
        fmonth = 03;
    }
    if (month[0] == 'M' && month[1] == 'a' && month[2] == 'y')
    {
        fmonth = 05;
    }

    return fmonth;
}
std::string genFname(std::string time)
{
    std::stringstream time4, time5, time6, time8, time9, time22, time24, time23;
    time4 << time[4];
    time5 << time[5];
    time6 << time[6];
    time9 << time[9];
    time24 << time[24];
    time23 << time[23];
    time22 << time[22];
    time8 << time[8];
    std::string t4, t5, t6, t8, t9, t24, t23, t22;
    time4 >> t4;
    time5 >> t5;
    time6 >> t6;
    time8 >> t8;
    time23 >> t23;
    time24 >> t24;
    time22 >> t22;
    time9 >> t9;
    std::string month, day, year, timeIns;
    month = t4 + t5 + t6;
    day = t8 + t9;
    year = t22 + t23 + t24;
    month = std::to_string(calcMon(month));
    timeIns = t8 + t9 + "_" + month + "_" + t22 + t23 + t24;
    std::string finalFname = "routine" + timeIns + ".txt";
    return finalFname;
}
void newRoutine(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ofstream file{fileName};
    task tasks[100];
    tasks[0].name = "wake up";
    std::cout << "I will ask you for your tasks in a moment.\nJust enter 'bedtime' when its your time to sleep";
    std::cout << "\nWhen do you plan to wake up?: ";
    std::cin >> tasks[0].stime;
    while (true)
    {
        int n = 1;
        std::string tName, strN;
        std::stringstream sample;
        sample << n;
        sample >> strN;
        std::cout << "Enter task " + strN + ": ";
        std::cin >> tName;
        tasks[n].name = tName;
        if (tName[0] == 'b' && tName[1] == 'e' && tName[2] == 'd' && tName[3] == 't' && tName[4] == 'i' && tName[5] == 'm' && tName[6] == 'e')
            break;
        n++;
    }
}
void oldRoutine(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream routine(fileName);
    std::string dummy;
    do
    {
        getline(routine, dummy);
        std::cout << dummy << std::endl;
    } while (!routine.eof()); //eof stands for end of file
    std::cout << "Thats it";
    routine.close();
}
void start(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ofstream routine(fileName);
    if (routine.fail())
    {
        std::cout<<"No routine found for today"<<std::endl;
        newRoutine(fileName);
    }
    if (routine.good())
    {
        std::cout<<"A routine found for today"<<std::endl;
        oldRoutine(fileName);
    }
    routine.close();
}
int main()
{
    time_t tt;
    struct tm *ti;
    time(&tt);
    ti = localtime(&tt);
    std::string time = asctime(ti);
    std::string finalFname = genFname(time);
    start(finalFname);
    // inp();
    getch();
}
```

Output

```
A routine found for today

That's it
```

Comment: Side mark: I would like to propose to put the months in either an `enum class` or an `std::map` (prefering `enum class` here).

Comment: The first thing you do in `start()` is `std::ofstream routine(fileName);` which will truncate the file. You probably should have used `std::ifstream routine(fileName)` and pass the opened file to `oldRoutine` by reference.

Comment: @taiBsu Okay, I know ```enum class``` but what is an ```std::map```

Comment: [std::map (cppreference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: When `std::ofstream file{fileName};` opens a file, it will remove, "truncate", the current contents. If you wish to add to a file, consider adding the `ios::app` open mode. [Documentation link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, so should I declare ```std::ofstream routine(fileName);``` as a global object or is there any other good way of doing it?

Comment: @watermelon Refresh screen and see my updated comment :)

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, let me research on ```ios:app``` as I am not much aware of it

Comment: Ted's updated comment has a much better option if suitable. Learn about open modes, though. They'll save you a bunch of time later.

Comment: [open modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

Comment: Okay, guys thank you very much for responding and trying to help. I will laern about these new things you introduced me to and will reply again if I have something to ask on ^ _ ^

Comment: Off-topic:  IMHO, a better method to convert from month name to integer is to use a table.  Use `std::find` on the array.  Much less code than what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if a file already exists. In your code, you create an `std::ofstream` object which creates a new file:
`std::ofstream routine(fileName);`

If you want to read from an existing file, try `std::ifstream` (explained [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)).